# Android UDP Client doesn't receive DatagramPacket

Tags: android, sockets, udp

WiBro, which is used as a server module and client Nexus Galaxy ICS.
Both machines are 3g UDP communication.
The server will return only the received data has been implemented.

dSocket.send (sendPacket) is a smooth communication.
However, we have a problem.
dSocket.receive (recvPacket) does not receive the data.

The server sends the packet is wrong? If the client receives the packet is wrong?
The server sends data but, telecom equipment is taken to preserve the situation?

When only sending a packet, the client has not a problem.
but after receive code implementation, the client has a problem.

```
private class ClientThread implements Runnable{

    @SuppressWarnings("finally")
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DatagramSocket dSocket = null;
        try{
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress.toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "Connecting");
            Log.d(TAG, "IP :::: " + serverAddr.toString());
            dSocket = new DatagramSocket(SERVERPORT);
            dSocket.setSoTimeout(5000);
            byte[] arr_RecvPacket = new byte[1024];
            connected = true;
            while(connected){
                try{
                    Log.d(TAG, "Sending Command :::: ( " + String.valueOf(i));
                    String strPacket = "Hey Server ( " + String.valueOf(i);
                    byte[] arr_Packet = strPacket.getBytes();
                    sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(arr_Packet, arr_Packet.length, serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
                    dSocket.send(sendPacket);
                    Log.d(TAG, "C:Send");
                    i++;
                    Log.d(TAG, "C:Make Recv Packet....");
                    recvPacket = new DatagramPacket(arr_RecvPacket, arr_RecvPacket.length);
                    Log.d(TAG, "C:Recving...");
                    dSocket.receive(recvPacket);
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0x01);
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(TAG, "S:Error");
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "S:DataSocket close");
            dSocket.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "C:Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
            connected = false;
        }finally{
            connected = false;
            if(dSocket != null){
                dSocket.close();
            }
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your 'connected' variable is misnamed. You are never really connected in UDP.

Comment: I knew, but udp does not maintain a connection. Am I not correct?

Comment: Exactly, so you can't have a 'connected' state either. So it is misnamed.

Comment: Do you control the server code?
Are you sure the server receives and process the command datagram?

Does receive() timeout after 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The server sends the packet is wrong?

Could be. Hard to say without seeing it. It should send the reply back to the IP:port embedded in the incoming datagram. Easiest way to do that is to reuse it, just change the data.

> the client receives the packet is wrong?

It looks OK.

> The server sends data but, telecom equipment is taken
>   to preserve the situation?

I don't know what this means.

Comment: Thanks EJP, third question means The Carrier Device(NAT, ROUTER, Etc...)blocks Galaxy Nexus public ip or something else.

Comment: @reinhard.lee Entirely possible.

Comment: Thank you. i think direct connection is impossible. maybe i need DNS or something like relay server between two devices.